# Java get REAL loopback address programmatically

Tags: java, sockets, citrix, loopback

I am developing a Java application which will listen a local port to communicate with another program. Normally it will listen to, say 127.0.0.1:8808.

One of my client reports that they are using Citrix environment, it is like MS remote desktop environment, multiple users can log in the same machine in the same time.

As you may know, such terminal server users share one loopback address, that means, only the first user run my application can successfully bind to 127.0.0.1:8808, the others will receive resource conflict error.

My client try to fix this by enable "virtual loopback", this setting can automatically assign different loopback address to different users, every user will get 127.0.0.2-127.0.0.255 as the loopback address instead of all 127.0.0.1,  that sound like a perfect solution for this situation.

A test shows virtual loopback works well for other programs like chrome and IE,  TCPView tool shows any connection to localhost are redirect to 127.0.0.2, except my program.

I am thinking the problem may be because I am using the fixed address 127.0.0.1 in the code, but I don't have an environment to confirm. So my question here is: Is there any Java method I can use to get the REAL loopback address in such situation, so I can bind to the the right address?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the real loop back address. You can use other addresses as loop back but this is the one most people use.

Comment: Did you do some research; like http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX209237

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks, that may be the root cause, I will ask my client have a try.

Comment: It would likely be easier to just change the port number for each user.

Comment: @Andreas I would say that's plan B, we are taking about hundreds even thousands of accounts per customer.

Comment: @John.D If you're talking *thousands*, then a solution using 127.0.0.2-127.0.0.255. i.e. only 254 different addresses, does not seem enough. Port numbers can so *thousands*, though.

Comment: @Andreas Let's say 1,000 users, 10 users on each machine (VM), virtual loopback is automatically done by Citrix app, no manual work needed. but assign 1,000 port on 100 machine, even it can be automated that's a lot of work to do.

Comment: Other programs work, but your program, which hardcodes 127.0.0.1 doesn't work. Doesn't that automatically suggests not to hardcode loopback address, but to use the named loopback address `localhost`, which might then be configured (by Citrix) to go to the appropriate virtual address for the user?

Comment: @Andreas just so others reading this will know this Citrix Loopback feature will keep rolling over to the next octet up to 127.255....... thats alot of ip's https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/xenapp-and-xendesktop/xenapp-6-5/xenapp65-w2k8-wrapper/ps-publishing-landing-page/ps-pub-virtual-ip-why-use-v2.html

Comment: @Andreas you are correct, specifying localhost fixes the problem and automatically resolves. the trick is you have to have all the stuff relying on this, running on the same citrix "machine" for this to work.